# add tabs in the sharepoint 2013 masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I need to show horizontal tabs on my SharePoint 2013 on premise masterpage below the banner .I am not good at the designing part, How can i achieve that . can anyone suggest me something?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Master Page in SharePoint Designer. Find the controls on the ribbon tab which needs to be inserted. You can add a label or any other control available. The script added in the Master Page should be inside the  tag.

Note:Make a copy of your master page before you screw up :P